# functions in knockout components (knockoutjs 3.2+)

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-components

I'm trying to understand knockout 3.2 components, but i'm stuck.

I have a component "Customers"

```
ko.components.register("customers", {
  viewModel: function (params) {
    var self = this;
    this.customers = ko.observableArray();
    this.selectedCustomerId = ko.observable(1);
    this.selectCustomer = function (data) {
        selectedCustomerId(data.Id);
    };

    $.getJSON('http://localhost:49435/Customer/GetCustomers', this.customers);
},
template: "<div><table class=\"table table-condensed table-responsive\"><thead><tr><th>Customer ID</th><th>Name</th><th>City</th></tr></thead><tbody data-bind=\"foreach: customers\"><tr><td data-bind=\"text: Id\"></td><td data-bind=\"text: Name, click: $root.selectCustomer\"></td><td data-bind=\"text: City\"></td></tr></tbody></table></div>"
});
```

But when binding, I get the following Error:

> Unable to process binding "click: function (){return
>   $root.selectCustomer }" Message: Cannot read property 'selectCustomer'
>   of undefined

Next thing I want to do is communicating the `selectedCustomerId` to another component. Is this possible using the PubSub Synchronization and how is this possible. Can someone give me a hint where to start.

Comment: Do you call ko.applyBindings anywhere? If so i think that the model which is passed to it as parameter is considered to be $root. Try to use $parent instead of $root.

Comment: this is in ko 3.3 milestone https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1449

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$parent` instead of `$root` in you bindings. `$root` generally refers to view model which is passed to `ko.applyBindings` method.

Also you have another error in your code - in `selectCustomer` method you are trying to access global variable `selectedCustomerId` which does not exist. You should prefix it with `self` to be able to access local variable which is created in your view model.

```
var self = this;
    self.customers = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedCustomerId = params.SelectedCustomer;
    self.selectCustomer = function (data) {
        self.selectedCustomerId(data.Id);
    };
```

Regarding passing `selectedCustomerId` to another component - you can create observable in your root view model (which you pass to `ko.applyBindings`) and then pass it to your components like this:

```
<customers params='SelectedCustomer:selectedCustomer'></customers>
```

And then use this observable when data binding.
Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pLjsyvom/) for the working example.

Comment: NOTE: under Yevgeniy's plan, you can then pass `selectedCustomerId` as the `SelectedCustomer` parameter to child components.  This way of doing things seemed weird to me at first but if you think about it, it has become the interface of the component to the outside world.  I think it would be good practice to spell out what parameters each component takes as a nicely formatted comment above wherever you define the component.  Also, take a look at how Steve Sanderson splits out html and js: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2014/06/11/architecting-large-single-page-applications-with-knockout-js/